# The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: npm, static

I am trying to run npm start and one of the scripts are

```
"build:mkdir": "mkdir -p build/js && mkdir -p build/js/vendor",
```

then i get this error

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! margo-static@1.0.0 build:mkdir: `mkdir -p build/js && mkdir -p build/js/vendor`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

any suggestion?
my platform is windows 10 , node version 12.15.0

Comment: same here, anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it has been long time but I was checking my questions
for this one I think modify the script will solve it

```
{


"scripts": {
    "build:mkdir": "mkdirp build/js && mkdirp build/js/vendor"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.5"
  }
}
```

as the environment is windows
The -p option with mkdir command is not recognized by Windows command line
and also don't forget to install mkdirp package

```
npm install --save-dev mkdirp
```